# How does the Monthly Active Users Statistic work in the Google Play Store Console

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I wanted to check the App statistics on the Google Play Store Console and I've found these statistics:

**Install base**
The number of active devices on which your app is installed. An active device is one that has been turned on at least once in the previous 30 days.

**Installed audience**
The number of users who have your app installed on at least one device that has been turned on in the last 30 days

**Daily active users (DAU)**
The number of users who opened your app on a given day

**Monthly active users (MAU)**
The number of users who opened your app in a 28-day period

So as I understood it, the difference between "Installed audience" and "MAU" is that "Installed audience" users have just the app installed and MAU are users that have also opened the app at least once. So every MAU should also be part of Installed audience and the number can not be higher than the Installed audience.

But these are roughly the numbers I got:
Install base: 21000
Installed audience: 18000
Daily active users: 7000
Monthly active users: 24000

So somehow MAU is actually the largest number, which doesn't make sense to me. So I guess I misunderstood something. Does anybody know how it works? Is it maybe not unique users?

[Where to find MAU in Play Store Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCm32.png)

Edit:
Also this is the explanation for the metrics used on MAU. Is it unique users or unique devices now?

> Unique users: The number of unique devices that an event happens to. Such as the number of unique devices that install your app.

I've contacted the googleplay developer support and they said MAU is counting every session on a device.
But this makes no sense either, cause in that case the numbers should be much higher and if it's actually not unique users then the numbers between DAU and MAU wouldn't work either.